# How to set up 3x3 CSS grid

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I am trying to create a responsive grid layout. However I have so far got to a 3x3 grid which has gone wrong. I have managed to get the squares spinning. However I can not seem to achieve the layout of it with the divs.

Can somebody please show me how to fix this and make this a 3x3 grid as I am so confused. My code is below.

***CSS***

```
.trigger {
   width:100%;
   height:400px;
   background-color:white; 
}

.hover-img, hover-img.hover_effect {
   background-color:white;
   position: relative;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 0;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-color: #4595ff;
}

.trigger:hover > .hover-img {
   -webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);
   -moz-transform:rotateY(360deg);
   -ms-transform:rotateY(360deg);
   -o-transform:rotateY(360deg);
   transform:rotateY(360deg);
   font-size:14px;
   color:white;
}

.img1 {
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

.img1:hover {
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img2 {
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img2:hover {
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img3 {
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
} 

.img3:hover {
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img4 {
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img4:hover {
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img5 {
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img5:hover {
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img6 {
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img6:hover {
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#container {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden; 
}

#column1 {
   float: left;
   width: 30%;
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-left: 2%;
   font-size: 12px
}

#column3 {
   float: left;
   width: 30%;
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-left: 2%;
   margin-bottom: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

***HTML***

```
<div id="container">
<div id="column1">
<div class="trigger">
<div tabindex="0" class="maincontentdiv4 hover-img img1" style="height: 390px;">
 </div>
</div>
<p></p>
<div class="trigger">
<div tabindex="0" class="maincontentdiv4 hover-img img2" style="height: 390px;">
</div>
</div>
<p></p>
</div>
<div id="column1">
<div class="trigger">
<div tabindex="0" class="maincontentdiv4 hover-img img3" style="height: 390px;"></div>
</div>
<p></p>
<div class="trigger">
<div tabindex="0" class="maincontentdiv4 hover-img img4" style="height: 390px;">
</div>
<div id="column3">
<div class="trigger">
<div tabindex="0" class="maincontentdiv4 hover-img img5" style="height: 390px;">
</div>
</div>
<p></p>
<div class="trigger">
<div tabindex="0" class="maincontentdiv4 hover-img img6" style="height: 390px;">
</div>
</div>
<p></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your Html is broken.  You did not close your second column or the .trigger div in that column.  Should work if you close those divs

Comment: I fixed your code and added comment in the html where it broke.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYOMdO

Comment: @JustinBreiland Thanks so much but I was asking how to make it a 3x3 could you show me? I would even like a 4x3! lol sorry for being cheeky. (4 columns i mean)hehe :)

Comment: on  .trigger change the width to 62%.  This will give the hover a smaller hit-box and will prevent multiple divs from being hovered at once.  Also, instead of using <p> tags add a margin-bottom to your trigger.

Comment: @JustinBreiland you truly are an amazing man, you thoroughly deserve your tick here lol, but could you please just read the comment above? sorry for taking the mic!

Comment: Do you need this to support IE?

Comment: yes please if thats ok :) i didnt realise it would be different

Comment: is IE 10+ support ok?

Comment: @JustinBreiland write it as an answer so I can tick you and give you the credit for it as you have been amazingly helpful and taught me a lot so far,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a 3x3 grid via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502266/how-do-i-create-a-3x3-grid-via-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is for All IE support 
[Codpen 1](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEWodG).

`code`

For IE 10+ using flexbox 
[Codepen 2](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYOMdO).

`code`

Comment: Superman will salute that person who will tell him the best resources to learn CSS quickly with solid concepts.