# How do I create a 3x3 grid via CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Given 9 `div`s one after another, I want to create a grid 3X3 via CSS.

How do I do that?

```css
.cell {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cell:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: #F00;
  /* what property should I use to get a line break after this element? */
}

/* this doesn't work; at least not in safari */
.cell:nth-child(3n)::after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Note:** I don't want `float/clear` solution. Focus is on CSS and not HTML restructure.

If I add `content: '\A'; white-space: pre;` to `::after` output comes out to be ugly.

```css
.cell {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cell:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: #F00;
  /* what property should I use to get a line break after this element? */
}

.cell:nth-child(3n)::after {
  display: inline;
  content: '\A';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

How do I go about getting all div in a 3X3 row-column layout?

Comment: Related: [Responsive CSS Grid with persistent aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51577807/104380)

Answer (score 43):

**02/2022 Update:** As David mentioned in the comments, `grid-gap` is now deprecated and was replaced with the tidier `gap`. I've updated the code snippet below to reflect this.

---

Now that [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) is <s>fairly</s> **very** [well supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid), I thought I'd supplement the others answers with a more modern solution.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

div > div {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: This is such a simple and elegant solution. +1

Comment: 'grid-gap' has now been deprecated in favor of 'gap'

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap

Comment: @AndyHoffman you know what, you are awesome

Answer (score 27):

This layout is simple with CSS flexbox. No changes to HTML.

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;                       /* establish flex container */
  flex-wrap: wrap;                     /* enable flex items to wrap */
  justify-content: space-around;
  
}
.cell {
  flex: 0 0 32%;                       /* don't grow, don't shrink, width */
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #999;
}
.cell:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

---

*Benefits of flexbox:*

1. minimal code; very efficient
2. [centering, both vertically and horizontally, is simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276)
3. [equal height columns are simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276)
4. [multiple options for aligning flex elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
5. it's responsive
6. unlike floats and tables, which offer limited layout capacity because they were never intended for building layouts, flexbox is a modern (CSS3) technique with a broad range of options.

---

*To learn more about flexbox visit:*

- [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
- [Using CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) ~ MDN
- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) ~ CSS-Tricks
- [What the Flexbox?!](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLu8EoSxDXHP7xj_y6NIAhy0wuCd4uVdid) ~ YouTube video tutorial

---

*Browser support:*

Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE < 10](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add prefixes use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).

Comment: Hi Anubhav - Thanks for the edit. I rolled it back only because it didn't work. If you want a pixel width for each cell, you need to specify a width on the container. Otherwise, they won't wrap unless the screen is very narrow. That's why I used percentages for the demo. What's the width of the container?

Comment: A. What do you mean it didn't work? B. I am not fixing `width`, I am setting upper limit to it. C. It wrapped on my 2000px wide monitor just fine. D. Did you even run the code?

Comment: I did run it. It showed a single row of items all the way through. That's why I rolled back the edit.

Comment: What browser are you using? version, os etc.?

Comment: Tested on current Chrome and FF. As I said in my first comment, they will wrap eventually, when the screen is narrow. On wider screen it's a single row. But if that's what you want, you're all set.

Comment: Okay. Just beware of browser compatibility. Here's [**Chrome**](http://imgur.com/9mfq73p) and [**Firefox**](http://imgur.com/PWN3bEo).

Comment: Also note that `calc` will not work with `flex-basis` component of `flex` shorthand property on IE11. You'll need to use `flex-basis` directly.

Comment: Good answer. As a side note, given the problems with the calc expression, and also for personal tastes, I would remove the horizontal margin and just set the flex-basis to say 30%. Given the proper justify-content, the separation between items will be responsive.

Answer (score 7):

Besides Excellent answer from @Michael_B to use `flexbox`, you can use

- **CSS tables**

  or
- **float:left**

  both to support old browsers such as IE 8/9 , which `flexbox` won't support.

**Note** IE8 won't support `nth-child` but supports `first/last-child`

#### Option1 (CSS Tables) : with changes to HTML, wrapping each 3 cells in a row.

```css
.grid {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 5px
}
.row {
  display: table-row
}
.cell {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  display: table-cell;
}
.row div:last-child {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

## Update

#### Option2 (`float:left`): with NO changes to HTML,  using `clear:left` at each (4th)n item.

```css
.cell {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px
}
.cell:first-child + div+ div,
.cell:first-child + div+ div + div + div + div,
.cell:first-child + div+ div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  background: red
}
.cell:first-child + div+ div + div,
.cell:first-child + div+ div + div + div + div + div,
.cell:first-child + div+ div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  clear: left
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Erm, I think IE 8 won't support `flexbox`. IE 9 does, partially. Crashes on `background` or some related property.

Comment: IE9 doesn't support at all, you can see here http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox, I just gave you another solution :)

Comment: Sorry my mistake. In my mind I was thinking about `calc`.

Comment: No problem ;), As I said just gave you a cross-browser solution.

Comment: This uses HTML restructuring.

Comment: @AnubhavSaini it is been a long time, but I've updated the answer with an option, if you want to take a look

Answer (score 3):

Just to add another, you can also make a 3x3 grid using only a single `<div>`. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3ubuKgyvkhP5UHpgxIUl?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<div class="grid"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid {
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-top: 50px solid red;
  border-bottom: 50px solid red;
  margin: 0 50px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: inset 0 4px 0 -2px white,
              inset 0 -4px 0 -2px white;
}
.grid::before {
  content: '';
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-top: 50px solid red;
  border-bottom: 50px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute; left: -52px; top: -50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 4px 0 -2px white,
              inset 0 -4px 0 -2px white;
}
.grid::after {
  content: '';
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-top: 50px solid red;
  border-bottom: 50px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute; right: -52px; top: -50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 4px 0 -2px white,
              inset 0 -4px 0 -2px white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is asking for a non-float clear solution, but after trying the flexbox solution I found that it did not preserve the width of my elements (further reading suggests I may have needed to set the width on the container element).  In the specific case of a 3x3 grid however (as opposed to a grid with n rows of three) that a float clear solution more concise and works nicely.  Here it is in case others find this answer when looking for a solution as I did:

```
.cell {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.cell:nth-child(4) {
  clear: left;
}
.cell:nth-child(7) {
  clear: left;
}
```