# How to make grid content autofill to the aspect ratio set?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, aspect-ratio

I'm making a logo soup/quilt thinking of some solution to make it easy. So I make a 3x3 grid and add `aspect-ratio: 2 / 1` to the grid elements. Now I want the `img`s inside to expand so they either fit the max height or max width. Somehow the whole grid either expands past the scroll bar or the aspect ratio is set, but the images do not expand.

```css
.grid-customers {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 50px;
    grid-row-gap: 30px;
    place-items: center;
}

.customer {
    aspect-ratio: 2 / 1;
}

.customer a img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-customers">
     <div class="customer customer-1">
         <a href="https://example.org/">
             <img src="media/logos/logo.png"/>
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class="customer customer-1">
         <a href="https://example.org/">
             <img src="media/logos/logo.png"/>
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class="customer customer-1">
         <a href="https://example.org/">
             <img src="media/logos/logo.png"/>
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class="customer customer-1">
         <a href="https://example.org/">
             <img src="media/logos/logo.png"/>
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class="customer customer-1">
         <a href="https://example.org/">
             <img src="media/logos/logo.png"/>
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class="customer customer-1">
         <a href="https://example.org/">
             <img src="media/logos/logo.png"/>
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class="customer customer-1">
         <a href="https://example.org/">
             <img src="media/logos/logo.png"/>
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class="customer customer-1">
         <a href="https://example.org/">
             <img src="media/logos/logo.png"/>
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class="customer customer-1">
         <a href="https://example.org/">
             <img src="media/logos/logo.png"/>
         </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51577807/responsive-css-grid-with-persistent-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 0):

If you want images to be scaled up, you'll need to set `width`, not `max-width`.

```
.customer a img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Or you can use `object-fit: contain;` if you prefer.

```css
.grid-customers {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 50px;
    grid-row-gap: 30px;
    place-items: center;
}

.customer {
    aspect-ratio: 2 / 1;
}

.customer a img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-customers">
     <div class="customer customer-1">
         <a href="https://example.org/">
             <img src="https://www.tailorbrands.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/mcdonalds-logo.jpg"/>
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class="customer customer-1">
         <a href="https://example.org/">
             <img src="https://www.tailorbrands.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/mcdonalds-logo.jpg"/>
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class="customer customer-1">
         <a href="https://example.org/">
             <img src="https://www.tailorbrands.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/mcdonalds-logo.jpg"/>
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class="customer customer-1">
         <a href="https://example.org/">
             <img src="https://www.tailorbrands.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/mcdonalds-logo.jpg"/>
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class="customer customer-1">
         <a href="https://example.org/">
             <img src="https://www.tailorbrands.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/mcdonalds-logo.jpg"/>
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class="customer customer-1">
         <a href="https://example.org/">
             <img src="https://www.tailorbrands.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/mcdonalds-logo.jpg"/>
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class="customer customer-1">
         <a href="https://example.org/">
             <img src="https://www.tailorbrands.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/mcdonalds-logo.jpg"/>
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class="customer customer-1">
         <a href="https://example.org/">
             <img src="https://www.tailorbrands.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/mcdonalds-logo.jpg"/>
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class="customer customer-1">
         <a href="https://example.org/">
             <img src="https://www.tailorbrands.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/mcdonalds-logo.jpg"/>
         </a>
     </div>
</div>
```